# How to created timeBased file in R

Tags: r, xts

I thought I would post here since I have spent hours trying to figure this out. So I'm working with a csv file with Date and Closing return price. However, I can't get the file to be "timeBased." (`timeBased` function is from package `xts`). For example:

```
timeBased(dfx)
[1] FALSE
```

Here is what I have:

```
dfx = xts(aus$AUS, order.by=as.Date(aus$DATE))
```

and here's what the first 10 rows look like of the file:

```
DATE    AUS
1   12/1/1988   -0.0031599720
2   12/2/1988   -0.0015724670
3   12/5/1988   -0.0000897619
4   12/6/1988   -0.0022670620
5   12/7/1988   0.0052895550
6   12/8/1988   -0.0048259860
7   12/9/1988   0.0106990910
8   12/12/1988  0.0033538810
9   12/13/1988  0.0118568700
10  12/14/1988  -0.0050105200
```

If anyone can help, I would appreciate it! I tried multiple codes using zoo and other edits, but nothing. Thank you!![enter image description here][1]

Comment: Also, with my dfx statement, some observations for to NA, not sure why. Thanks again

Comment: What's in your `aus` dataframe? Can you provide some sample rows? Otherwise it's hard to help you.

Comment: `?timeBased` says, "Used to verify that the object is one of the known time-based classes in R." and "Current time-based objects supported are 'Date', 'POSIXct', 'chron', 'yearmon', 'yearqtr', and 'timeDate'." xts is not one of the listed classes, so I'm not sure why you expect `timeBased` to return `TRUE` for a xts object. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Joshua Ulrich points out, using the `timeBased` function with an xts object should be expected to return `FALSE`.  In addition to that, there may be another problem with your code.  Assuming that your example displays the contents of `aus`, then `aus$DATE` is actually a factor or character data, not a Date object.  To properly convert to an xts object, you'll have to specify the date format of the `aus$DATE` data.  To convert and then test whether `dfx` is an xts object, you could use the following code:

```
 dfx = xts(aus$AUS, order.by=as.Date(aus$DATE, "%m/%d/%Y"))
 dfx
                [,1]
1988-12-01 -0.0031599720
1988-12-02 -0.0015724670
1988-12-05 -0.0000897619
1988-12-06 -0.0022670620

timeBased(dfx)
[1] FALSE

is.xts(dfx)
[1] TRUE
```